# Остановка ввода без enter в си

Tags: c, stdin

Написал програму, которая первые 10 символов с клавиатуры записывает в файл, но проблема в том, что я могу ввести и 100 символов, а программа завершиться только когда я нажму enter, как сделать сохранение в файл до нажатия клавиши enter или просто хотя бы завершить работу по факту ввода 10 символов. (OS Windows).

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int c,i=0;
    freopen("OUTPUT.txt", "w", stdout);
    while ((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF && i<10) {
        putc(c, stdout);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Заменить оператор `&&` на `||`.

Comment: Возможно Вам [это](https://web.archive.org/web/20180401093525/http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/04/08/non-blocking-user-input-in-loop-without-ncurses/) поможет. Можно отключить канонический режим для stdin и не зависеть от нажатия enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел способ проще, использовал getch()

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    freopen("OUTPUT.txt", "w", stdout);
    while (c = _getch()) {
        putc(c, stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Советую в подобных вопросах всегда указывать OS, для которой вы пишете программу.

Comment: Пишу для OS windows

Comment: Из ответа (в нем `<conio.h>`) это понятно. Я говорю про **задаваемые вопросы**

Comment: Исправил, спасибо за замечание

Answer (score -1):

stdin - это не устройство, а **буферируемый** файл. Передача блока данных от драйвера клавиатуры в прикладную программу произойдёт только **после** нажатия клавиши Enter.

Для того, что бы работать на уровне отдельного нажатия клавиши на клавиатуре необходимы другие средства.

Проще всего - использовать библиотеку *ncurses*. Она большая и довольно сложная, но там есть посимвольный ввод/вывод.

Comment: Вариант в комментарии выше использует меньше памяти чем ncurses